# Richtext field does not render all the doclinks

Tags: xpages, richtextbox, lotus-domino

Application stores big amount (~10k) of rather big rich text (many hundreds/few thousands lines) hyperlinked documents. Content of the rich text fields is updated by Lotus Notes rich client and users link documents by  standard "Copy as Link/Paste" procedure. It creates doclinks looking like small yellow document icon (or the ones with anchor - navigating to specific position within rich text). These icons rendered in XPage look the same.

Documents are NOT saved/updated by web interface/XPage.

The problem: for long RTF content, after ~1200 rendered doclinks they stop showing/rendering (even in HTML source). Exact number of rendered doclinks vary from document to document.

MIME encoding is not a solution. Documents whose RTF was converted to MIME have two unacceptable side effects:

- Those nice images for doclinks are rendered as blue `[Link]` text.
- Much worse, rich text field control does not translate doclinks to (expected) `https://` URL, they stay in `notes://` format.

Is there some internal limit that prevents rendering such count of standard doclinks? Is there any workaround to render long rich text fields with many doclinks?

**Update:**

`server/db.nsf/0/unid/Body?OpenField` output is affected by this bug too.

Comment: Did you check the raw richtext using http://yourserver/someDB.nsf/0/unid/Body?OpenField to see if the issue is already there!

Comment: You might want to check AppsFidelity from Geniisoft

Answer (score 2):

I had a chat with Ben from Geniisoft and he verified that there’s a limit for DocLinks that AppFidelity overcomes. So you want to have a license for that. Besides overcoming your problem at hand, it is a complete beauty makeover for your HTML rendered.

From Ben:

> I saw that you mentioned AppsFidelity on StackOverflow. I don't have enough reputation points to comment, but I just tested and it handled 4000 doclinks and turned them all into web URLs. I tried with AppsFidelity turned off, and it stopped rendering after fewer than 2000. Don't think I've ever tried that before.

### Update

Ben being Ben, he recreated the issue and showcased the solution in [this video on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/GeniiSoftware/videos/10156114804600126/). Enjoy!

Comment: Thx to Obi Wan Langhinrichs for the solution video: https://www.facebook.com/GeniiSoftware/videos/10156114804600126/